# linked list queue. stuck on pointers (I think)

Tags: c, list, linked-list

When I run these methods My list never grows and I don't know why. The head and tail are always equal. Is there something wrong with my pointers or struct setup? I spent 4 hours on this switching things around and I just can't seem to find why things aren't working unless it's a pointer thing (which I am learning and not good with)..

```
typedef struct EmployeeStruct
{
    char LastName[10];
    char FirstName[10];
    struct EmployeeStruct *next;  
} Employee;

struct EmployeeStruct *head,*tail, *temp;

Employee* hireEmployee(Employee* head, char LastName[10], char FirstName[10])
{
    // exit if max number of employees is reached
    if(eNum > MAX_EMPLOYEES)
    {
        printf("Sorry, but you can't hire any more employees right now\n");
        return 0;
    }
    // insert at tail
    newHire = head;
    while(newHire->next != NULL)
    {
        newHire = newHire->next;
        printf("nope\n");
    }
    // allocate memory
    newHire->next = malloc(sizeof(Employee));

    if(newHire == NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory allocation failed");
        return 0;
    }

    newHire->next = NULL;
    // insert values into this node
    strcpy(newHire->LastName, LastName );
    strcpy(newHire->FirstName, FirstName );
    newHire->EmployeeNumber = eNum;
    tail = newHire;
    //printf("%d\n",newHire->EmployeeNumber);
    eNum+=1;

    //printf("%d\n",newHire->EmployeeNumber);
    return newHire;
}

int main()
{  
    char choice;
    char first[20];
    char last[20];
    int i = 0;
    // allocate memory
    head = malloc(sizeof(Employee));

    if(head == NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory allocation failed");
        return 0;
    }
    head->next = tail;

    while(TRUE)
    {
        // prompt user for choice
        printf("Please choose from the following options:\n");
        printf("a: Hire new employee\nb: Promote employee\nc: Delete employee\nd: Display roster\ne: Exit\n");
            scanf("\n%c", &choice);

        switch(choice)
        {
            case 'a':
                printf("New employees first name:\n");
                    scanf("%s", first);
                printf("New employees last name:\n");
                    scanf("%s", last);
                tail = hireEmployee(head,last,first);
                temp = head;
                while(temp->next != NULL)
                {
                    temp = temp->next;
                    printf("nope\n");
                }
                temp->next = tail;
                tail = temp->next;
                printf("A%d: %s %s\n", tail->EmployeeNumber,tail->FirstName,tail->LastName);
                tail = tail->next;
                printf("A%d: %s %s\n", tail->EmployeeNumber,tail->FirstName,tail->LastName);
                tail->next = NULL;
                //printEmployees(head);
                break;
            case 'b':
                //TBD
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

** Works now, it was these four errors:

```
(newHire == NULL)    
(head == NULL)
newHire =newHire->next;
temp->next = tail;
```

BTW, I always do my homework and attend class, and I was simply stuck on a small piece of a MUCH larger program. So thank you to those who didn't insult me and actually gave useful advice. I truly appreciate it.

Comment: Lot many compilation errors..have tried to compile it... eNum you have used without declaring it

Comment: It's your homework then nobody is going to help you man... just try with yourself and ask only the doubt you have in this question ...because nobody is going to give you full solution ..

Comment: I don't want a full sollution. That's why I just posted the parts that are not working. I just want to know what is wrong with my pointers to head and tail because when I try to set the next nodes they never change.

Comment: Start at the beginning of main(), look at what head is assigned to, then look at what head->next is assigned to, then think about where tail is (or is *not*) initialized. Start with that, (which, btw, has little to do with your *real* problem).

Comment: Assuming you attended class, did your instructor mention, even in passing, the concept of modularizing your linked list functionality into specific routines (ll_pushhead, ll_pushtail, ll_pophead, ll_poptail, ll_head, ll_tail, ll_count, to rattle off the most obvious)? writing those, *testing those* and then integrating them into your assignment will be a *much* better use of your time than trying to spaghetti-code a solution. With those in-hand, you'd be amazed how much easier the rest of the assignment is. Just consider it.

Comment: No, she didn't. The problem is I not the linked list structure, I can code them in java no problem without any imports. I'm just not comfortable enough with C yet to know the subtleties of structs, pointers, and malloc. Thank you for the advice though, I do appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are your mistakes

```
newHire->next = malloc(sizeof(Employee));
```

the return type of malloc is void* so change it to

```
newHire->next = (EmployeeStruct *)malloc(sizeof(Employee));

if(newHire == NULL)
```

it will never be NULL change it to

```
if(newHire->next == NULL)
```

also change

```
newHire->next = NULL;
```

you have to traverse one more time link

```
newHire=newHire->next;
newHire->next = NULL;
```

Comment: @BhavikShah The other solution is just **not** to cast the return of `malloc`, like he did in his code. `void*` is implicitly convertible to `Employee*` (or any other pointer type). By the way, use either `Employee` or `struct EmployeeStruct`, but not just `EmployeeStruct`. Of course those two points only hold if it is really C that he's compiling and not C++ disguised as C.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in here

```
temp->next = tail;
tail = temp->next;
```

inside your `case 'b'`

because it making `temp->next` to its `head`